# HTML page, how to convert it to a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed a website's "index.html" with all the sections (header, content, footer, etc) made with Bootstrap 3.

It is meant to be the "design" to show to the user.

Now I have to port it to make it a Wordpress theme (because we are using Wordpress).

This is the first time and I have to do it quick,

Does Wordpress offer a base skeleton to apply my HTML sections and CSS/JS? I mean just a "blank" theme, maybe object oriented (like Symfony).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use starter themes to make your work easy and quick.
Find a list of starter themes below: 
http://underscores.me/ 
https://roots.io/sage/ 
http://themble.com/bones/ 
The first one is my favourite though. But feel free to try them all out and make your pick.

Take a look at the WordPress Template Hierarchy; Will do u a lot of good: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Im liking Sage so far because of docs and explanations, so I will be taking it. Thanks!

Comment: Good. If you need more help, come back for it.

Comment: I ended using underscores, because Sage has some dependencies on nodejs packages, that I wasn't able to make work and I don't have the time needed to learn it. Maybe I will give a try later when I'm not burning... underscore was just simple and I am already customizing it.

Comment: Brilliant. _'s does it easy.